# XPath: Get value of a node to add up and compare

Tags: xpath

I ran over a problem which I can't seem to solve.
I got the following xml snippet:

```
<ex:SummeKapital vtNr="1234567890">
<ex:sum_kap_g waehrung="EUR">1340,06</ex:sum_Avmg_Ges>
<ex:sum_kap_a waehrung="EUR">1234,45</ex:sum_gef_Kap>
<ex:sum_kap_b waehrung="EUR">105,61</ex:sum_ungef_Kap>
</ex:SummeKapital>
```

I would like to add both the numbers from kap_a and kap_b, and compare them to the total of kap_g.

I am pretty inexperienced with xpath, can somebody try and help me figure this out?
Much regards!

My current prompt looks like this:

`number(//*[name() = "ex:sum_kap_a"]/text()) + number(//*[name() = "ex:sum_kap_b"]/text()) = number(//*[name() = "sum_kap_g"]/text())`

I tried to break it down, to get to the core of it and it seems that `number(//*[name() = "ex:sum_kap_a"]/text())` always comes back as NaN. Even a simple `//*[name() = "ex:sum_kap_a"]/text()` does not return "1234,45" but rather a text element which contains the textContent "1234,45".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath1:

```
translate(//*[name() = "sum_kap_a"]/text(), ",", ".") + translate(//*[name() = "sum_kap_b"]/text(), ",", ".") = translate(//*[name() = "sum_kap_g"]/text(), ",", ".")
```

or

```
//*[name() = "sum_kap_a"]/translate(text(), ",", ".") + //*[name() = "sum_kap_b"]/translate(text(), ",", ".") = //*[name() = "sum_kap_g"]/translate(text(), ",", ".")
```

You need `fn:translate()` to substitute commas to dots to treat them as numbers.

Comment: This was a very good hint, but I figured it must be written like this (xpath doesn't recognise translate as a node):

translate(//*[name() = "sum_kap_a"]/text(), ",", ".") + translate(//*[name() = "sum_kap_b"]/text(), ",", ".") = translate(//*[name() = "sum_kap_g"]/text(), ",", ".")

If you can change it in your answer, I would be more than happy to checkmark your answer. 

Thank you so much for helping!